# System tests VS integration tests Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Before upgrading to rails 5.1 i test my rails app via integration tests. And 70% of my rails app is automated via integration tests. Means all of application simple and complex behaviors are automated via integration tests. Off-course rails did not provided any java-script based testing.

With Arrival of Rails 5.1 they include system tests and said that every app interact with java-script and now you can test your app end to end scenarios like a real user interacting with browser. **So my manager ask me to move all integration tests to system tests**. Ok good! we can test our application the way our users experience it and help us test JavaScript as well.

Definitely system test can cover almost all integration tests as well. **So whats the importance of integration testing now ?**

> Why should someone write integration test in Rails 5.1 when he can
>   write same test case in System test?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder the same, but from [this](https://chriskottom.com/blog/2017/04/full-stack-testing-with-rails-system-tests/) I get the impression that system tests will replace integration testing - however, the only drawback seems to be speed and resource usage.